# Не работает скрипт для аккордеона

Tags: jquery

Не могу понять, почему не работает скрипт jQuery для аккордеона:
(Только начинаю учить JS, не злитесь)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class = "accordeonButton btn btn-primary w-50 mt-1"> Кнопка 1</div>
    <div class = "accordeonCard card card-body  w-50 mx-auto">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>

    <div class = "accordeonButton btn btn-primary w-50 mt-1"> Кнопка 2</div>
    <div class = "accordeonCard card card-body  w-50 mx-auto">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("accordeonButton").click(function(){
        var accordeonCards = $("accordeonCard");

        for (var i = 0; i < accordeonCards.length; i++){
            accordeonCards[i].hide();
        }

        $(this).next().show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Проблема тут: `$("accordeonButton")`. А потом будет еще и тут: `$("accordeonCard");` . А цикл, ко всему прочему, не нужен абсолютно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы достать элемент с классом, нужно поставить точку перед его названием `$('.класс')` Без этого, ваш $("accordeonButton") ищет на странице теги `<accordeonButton></accordeonButton>` и не находит их.

А здесь

```
for (var i = 0; i < accordeonCards.length; i++){
  accordeonCards[i].hide();
}
```

в переменной `accordeonCards` вы хотели сохранить набор элементов, полученных через jQuery... а такая запись `$(".accordeonButton")[номер]` просто не работает. Чтобы получить конкретный элемент из jQuery коллекции, пишут `$(".accordeonButton").eq(номер)` но в этом случае это не нужно, т.к. `$(".accordeonButton").hide()` и так "за кулисами" делает перебор и скрывает все найденные элементы с этим классом.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".accordeonButton").on('click', function() {
    $(".accordeonCard").hide();
    $(this).next().show();
  });
  
});
```

```css
.accordeonButton {
  margin: 5px; padding: 4px 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  cursor: pointer; width: 150px;
}

.accordeonCard { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="accordeonButton btn btn-primary w-50 mt-1"> Кнопка 1</div>
  <div class="accordeonCard card card-body  w-50 mx-auto">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

  <div class="accordeonButton btn btn-primary w-50 mt-1"> Кнопка 2</div>
  <div class="accordeonCard card card-body  w-50 mx-auto">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Перевод на JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let accordeonButton = document.querySelectorAll('.accordeonButton');
  let accordeonCard   = document.querySelectorAll('.accordeonCard');

  // в jQuery on('click'.. тоже за кадром делает перебор
  for( let i = 0; i < accordeonButton.length; i++ ){
    // По очереди на все кнопки вешается событие "клик"
    accordeonButton[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

      for( let j = 0; j < accordeonCard.length; j++ ){
        accordeonCard[j].style.display = "none";
      } // циклом прошли - скрыли все тексты.

      this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block"; // Показали нужный
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Проверю Ваш код, когда дома буду